# Conditionally inherit from pure base class

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, c++14

Suppose I have the following class definitions

```
struct base {
  virtual int f() = 0;
};

struct A: public base {
  int f() final { return 1; }
};

struct B: public base {
  int f() final { return 2; }
};
```

Is it possible to turn `A` and `B` into templates that take a `bool` parameter that specifies whether to inherit from the `base` or not? I have usage cases that do or don't require a base class providing a common interface.

Assume that `A` and `B` have a lot of member functions, so duplicating implementation would be tedious. But `sizeof(A)` and `sizeof(B)` are small.

Comment: Do you need two versions? Assuming `base` only contains abstract functions there shouldn't be any runtime cost. In your example your optimizer should see that any `A` is going to use `f()` from there since it is `final`.

Comment: @Guvante : It makes the type polymorphic, which gives it a vtable. Not a runtime cost, but a cost nonetheless.

Comment: @Guvante The size of the inheriting type is larger by the size of a pointer, which points to the vtable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I came up with the more direct approach I was looking for, without code duplication.

```
struct base {
  virtual int f() = 0;
};

struct empty_base { };

template <bool Inherit>
struct A final: public std::conditional_t<Inherit,base,empty_base> {
  int f() { return 1; }
};
```

Answer (score 5):

Sure:

```
template <bool> struct A
{
    // ...
};

template <> struct A<true> : base
{
    // ...
};
```

(Note that you could make `A<true>` derive from `A<false>` if that avoids redundancy.)

For example:

```
template <bool> struct A
{
    void f() { std::cout << "A::f called\n"; }
};

template <> struct A<true> : A<false>, base
{
    void f() override { A<false>::f(); }
};

int main()
{
    A<false> a1;
    A<true> a2;
    a1.f();
    a2.f();
    static_cast<base&>(a2).f();
}
```

Comment: I though that this wouldn't allow for `A<true> a; base* p = &a; p->f();` to work properly. I guess that would only happen if `base::f()` wasn't abstract (diamond problem). Does your implementation make the `p->f()` call any slower than in my original implementation?

Comment: If there any way to make `A<true>::f()` `final`?

Comment: You would need to copy the declaration (and call the other one via `A<false>::f()`). Also if you put `f()` in `A<false>` it would not satisfy the `base::f()` being abstract requirement.

Comment: @SU3: No, the overrider has to be declared in the overriding class. Let me edit the code.

Comment: Thanks, @KerrekSB. But one of the points of my question was that I wanted a method for doing this without duplicating all the function definitions.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using a pure base class the distinction shouldn't be important as your optimizer will avoid the virtual function call when you call `A::f()` since there will never be a derived class that implements a different version of `f()`.

Also you can instead do `class A final : base` if you don't plan on inheriting from `A` to avoid having to add `final` to each function.

Comment: Thanks. I forgot that you can stick `final` on the class instead of functions.

Comment: You can also do `class A sealed : public base { ... };`

Comment: What is `sealed`? Is that a Microsoft extension?

Comment: @SU3 : Yes, it was MS' implementation of `final` pre-C++11. (It's still necessary in C++/CLI rather than `final`, but that's not relevant here.)